# How to prevent jQuery from loading during ajax callback

Tags: 7, javascript

Using Drupal 7's implementation of jQuery and Drupal.behaviors, how can I get some of my jQuery to run ***only once*** when the page is initially loaded, and the rest to run when the page is loaded ***AND*** during AJAX callbacks.

How can I prevent ajax callbacks from triggering certain parts of my Drupal.behaviors?

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.fsrevs_user = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            //I want to run this only during the first page load.
            jQuery('#edit-message').after('<div>Do Once</div>');

            //I want this to run during first load and during each ajax callback.
            jQuery('#edit-message').after('<div>Do Every Time</div>');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
var msg = $('#edit-message');
msg.once('fsrevs_user', function() {
  msg.after('<div>Do Once</div>');
});

msg.after('<div>Do Every Time</div>');
```

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler than I thought it would be.  Thank you @Clive.

Comment: No worries :) `once()` is a Drupal thing but I'd guess it's just a really simple wrapper. You can do the same thing in one line with normal jQuery: `msg.not('.processed').addClass('processed').each(function() { ... });`

Comment: I was wondering why .once() was showing up as undefined in my editor. Makes sense that it is a wrapper.  Thank you for the jQuery there as well, that will be handy in other places as well.